# EventStore Persistent Subscription Event Data

Tags: eventstoredb

I am successfully connecting to an [EventStore](https://eventstore.org/) persistent subscription and using the EventStore ClientAPI in C#, I receive events. Everything is good except rather than receive the original event data in my `ResolvedEvent` I receive a reference to the event in the form `<event_number>@<stream_Id>`.

This is OK but to retrieve the event and process it requires me to do another trip to the EventStore and request the event using

```
ReadEventAsync(string stream, long eventNumber, bool resolveLinkTos);
```

Is there a way to receive the actual event data from the persistent subscription?

Comment: Are you reading from a stream where you have written the events directly, or from a projected stream? And have you specified that you want to resolve `LinkTo` events in the configuration when you start reading?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `ResolveLinkTos()` when creating a persistent subscription. This code works:

```
var subscriptionSettings = PersistentSubscriptionSettings.Create()
    .StartFromBeginning()
    .ResolveLinkTos()
    .WithMaxRetriesOf(_retryCount);
```

Comment: Thanks Alexey... I am away right now but as soon as I return I'll check this out and mark it answered if all is good, no doubt this is what I am missing...